# Why is my solution printed out in one list and not per item?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am pretty new to python and I would like to simulate a very simplistic truck-to-door assignment. I would like to have my feasible doors ‘d’ arranged per truck ‘t’. However, if I am running the simulation below it gives me a list of the feasible doors in total (so feasible doors of T1 and T2 together):

['D1', 'D2', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']

But I would like to have:

T1 = [‘D1’, ‘D2’]

T2 = [‘D1’, ‘D2’, 'D3']

This is important because, after this, I want to compare the different doors according to their cost and based on that choose the best door for each truck 't'.

```
# define dataset trucks and doors
trucks = ['T1', 'T2']
doors = ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4']

# define arrival time trucks 
arr_time = {
    'T1': 08.00,
    'T2': 09.00,
}

# define when door 'd' is free
free_time_door = {
    'D1': 07.00,
    'D2': 08.00,
    'D3': 09.00,
    'D4': 10.00
}

# define when door 'd' is feasible for truck 't' to assign to
def feasible_doors(trucks):
    feasible = []
    for t in trucks:
        for d in doors:
            if arr_time[t] >= free_time_door[d]:
                feasible.append(d)
    return feasible 

print (feasible_doors(trucks))
```

Comment: Because you only ever created one list, `feasable`, in your function. Why are you surprised that it does not become two lists magically?

Comment: You're instanciating only one list (`feasible`), so you only get one list. I suspect you want to create `feasible` inside the `for t in trucks` loop, and return a list containing all the created `feasible`.

Comment: I also suggest that you use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime), or even better [`arrow`](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to make operation on date or time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in order to get the the feasible doors for each trucks in one variable.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# define when door 'd' is feasible for truck 't' to assign to
def feasible_doors(trucks):
    feasible = defaultdict(list)
    for t in trucks:
        for d in doors:
            if arr_time[t] >= free_time_door[d]:
                feasible[t].append(d)
    return feasible 

print (feasible_doors(trucks))
```

Will output:

```
{'T2': ['D1', 'D2', 'D3'], 'T1': ['D1', 'D2']}
```

**EDIT**: more info on `defaultdict`

To select the doors for the truck, you just have to pass the key as parameters of your dict:

```
feasible = feasible_doors(trucks)

print feasible['T1']
# ['D1', 'D2']
```

Or loop on it using `items()`:

```
for key, values in feasible.items():
  if key == 'T1':
    doors = ', '.join(values)
    print('The truck: {truck} have {doors} doors free.'.format(truck=key, doors=doors))
# The truck: T1 have D1, D2 doors free.
```

Comment: Thank you, because this is exactly what I asked for! However, I would also like to be able to print the feasible doors just for one truck. So e.g. I would like to print the feasible doors just for T1, instead of showing me a print with all the feasible doors. (see comment above). Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Hi @Eline, I hope my example is good enough for your usage. Besides, please do not hesitate to have a look a the documentation as it will explain things way better than I do.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful! And I agree that I should use different values for the time indication, but for now, I just wanted to solve this problem with these values. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to build another list in the inner list and append that to the list returned:

```
# define when door 'd' is feasible for truck 't' to assign to
def feasible_doors(trucks):
    feasible = []
    for t in trucks:
        feasible_truck = []
        for d in doors:
            if arr_time[t] >= free_time_door[d]:
                feasible_truck.append(d)
        feasible.append(feasible_truck)
    return feasible
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I see what I did wrong now. However, now I would like to print the feasible doors for just 1 truck instead of a list with feasible doors for all the trucks. I tried to print e.g. feasible_doors('T1') and feasible_doors(trucks[0]) but then I get an error saying 'KeyError 'T''. I understand that something is wrong with calling the key values for truck 'T1'. But I don't understand why. 

So I would like to print the feasible doors just for T1. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Once again I am new to python, so thank you for your help and patience!